# fetch current time by using aem-sightly

Tags: aem, sightly

I'm new to aem. I'm trying to implement the following example in aem by using sightly. currently im working on aem 6.1.

can you please guide me how can i access current time in sightly. 
I'm using dialog boxes to show greeting messages according to current time.

```
<div data-sly-use.clientlibInclude="${'/libs/granite/sightly/templates/clientlib.html'}"></div>
<output data-sly-call="${clientlibInclude.css @ categories='angular-global-category'}" data-sly-unwrap />
<html> `enter code here`
<head>
    <title>Greeting Message using JavaScript</title> 
</head>

<body>  
<section class="intro">
 <h1> <label id="lblGreetings"></label></h1></section>
</body>
<script>

    var myDate = new Date();
    var hrs = myDate.getHours();

    var greet;

    if (hrs < 12)
        greet = 'Good Morning';
    else if (hrs >= 12 && hrs <= 17)
        greet = 'Good Afternoon';
    else if (hrs >= 17 && hrs <= 24)
        greet = 'Good Evening';


    document.getElementById('lblGreetings').innerHTML =
        '' + greet + ' Julio';

</script> 
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the time into the HTML markup when rendering it on the server? Or are you trying to get the time on the client side using Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no native objects that contain server date information in sightly. To print a date with sightly you need to have a Model related to it and use it within sightly. You can have a javascript model or a java one.
quick js guide found on the net: http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/htl-javascript-use-api/

If you'd want to go with Java I'd advise using SlingModels or Slice for modelling.

Seems to me you didn't do much reading on sighlty. Please read the docs first.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can create a java.util.Date as a model:

```
<sly data-sly-use.time="java.util.Date">${time.hours}</sly>
```

But that's just for fun or debugging, and not good style - I think it's much better do move such logic into a model, Java or otherwise. (And this just uses the default timezone...)